# Back button to navigate only up

Tags: android, navigation, back

In my app there is Activity A (main, parent) and B (child). When user is on A I want Back button to exit the app, not to go to history (B-A-B-A etc), since it makes no sense in this app. A has a ListView populated from sqlite, with items edited in B. If I call finish() in B after or instead intent to return to A, LisView(A) doesn´t get updated (I already call notifyDataSetChanged() in onCreate and onResume). I already navigated similar posts but couldn't find a solution to my case

Comment: Why are you createing a new intent to return to A the back button should return you to A when B is closed

Comment: You need to use `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);` instead of `startActivity(intent);` and when you edit any item in `Activity B` then call `setResult(resultCode)` before calling `finish()`. And get the data from the database in `onActivityResult()` in `Activity A`.

Comment: How do you return to A from B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```